# RAW Device mappings

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am new to ESXi, I am going to be using a hard disk attached to my VM with Raw device mappings that connects back to our SAN.

What are the recommended options to choose?

Where to store the LUN mappings, on the VM or with the Datastore?

What compatibility mode to use physical or virtual?

We are going to be using this for database server in our dev environment.

Comment: Why do you think you need an RDM? what are you trying to actually achieve, functionally I mean? Presumably the DB server is a VM right? is it part of a cluster, is that why you want RDMs?

Answer (score 0):

Generic recommendation is to store LUN mapping with VM and use physical compatibility. If you need the other options, you'll know why.